# Click event not working on button of dynamic generated table

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to submit the data filled in the input boxes which is generated dynamically  to the database on button click event of dynamically generated table but the click event is not working any idea would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#openForm").click(function () {
           $("#pdfFormInsideTblRight").after("<table class='table table-bordered'><thead class='thead-inverse'><tr><th class='text-left'>Properties</th>" +
                        "<th>Detail</th></tr></thead>" +
                        "<tr><td class='text-left'><strong>Product Group</strong></td>" +
"<td><input type='file' id='imgInp'/>" +
                        "<div><img id='blah' src='#' alt='your image' height='200px;'/></div></td></tr></table>");
  $("#pdfFormInsideTblRight ~ table").attr('id', 'mainTbl').addClass('table');
                var r = $(' <input type="button" ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export"  value="Export"  />');
                $("#mainTbl").append(r);
                var s = $(' <input type="button" ID="btnFrmSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  value="FrmSubmit"  />');
                $("#btnExport").after(s);
}

        });

    });
```

bind event jquery

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=btnFrmSubmit]").bind("click", function () {
            alert("hi");        
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @pedram is this fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *dynamically generated* or objects that added after `DOM` you should use `on` function:

```
 $(function () {
   $(document).on("click","[id*=btnFrmSubmit]", function () {
      alert("hi");        
    });
 });
```